# SQL create range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to design a database for a game and I'm stumped on how to do the link between the players exp and levels within the database based off a range. Something like level 1 is 0 xp, level 2 requires 200 exp, 3 requires 400, 4 requires 800 and so on and I want to be able to go "The player has 54234 exp. He's level 23" from a query that doesn't have the conversion built in.

In every example I've ever seen (in the similar grade scale example) they have a student is assigned a grade of say an A and they entirely skip over the fact that the student got a 92 which can be represented as an A. How do people using a database of students grades go from "His average score was a 73.9" to "He got a C"?

In a simplified version of the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Hero
(
   hero INT NOT NULL,
   totalExpEarned INT NOT NULL,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY(hero)
);

CREATE TABLE Level
(
   level INT NOT NULL,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY(level)
)
```

The easiest way I can think to do this would be a lookup table that went something like from 0-199 is level 1, from 200-399 is level two, and so on which is a horrible way to do it.

Comment: Honestly I think that's the kind of problem where it is good to skip "good design" rules and just precalculate it. That is, I'd have an "experience" field and a "level" field and every time I update experience, calculate the level with, say, PHP and if it's different from the level that is currently held then update it. It involves much simpler queries and the overhead should be insignificant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the range as two columns into your Level table, a min and max for experience. The max in my example is exclusive, while the min is inclusive.

```
CREATE TABLE Level
(
    level INT NOT NULL,
    minExp INT NOT NULL,
    maxExp INT NOT NULL
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(level)
)
```

Then you can just join Level and Hero:

```
SELECT hero, totalExpEarned
FROM Hero
INNER JOIN Level ON Hero.totalExpEarned >= Level.minExp
                    AND Hero.totalExpEarned < Level.maxExp
```

The levels would be set up like:

```
Level 1: minExp=0, maxExp=200
Level 2: minExp=200, maxExp=400
Level 3: minExp=400, maxExp=800
```

This approach allows you to look up the level with only one row per level, but you'll have to modify your schema.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. I'll probably do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

With your existing schema, you can do something like:

```
SELECT   Hero.hero, MAX(Level.level)
FROM     Level JOIN Hero ON Hero.totalExpEarned >= Level.level
GROUP BY Hero.hero
```

Comment: From reading this it seems it would always grab the max level possible and not the actual level they're at.

Comment: @user2309351: That's not correct.  The join criterion adds the necessary restriction.

Comment: I just tested it. It did only grab the last level.